# HTTP request aborted when app going background on iOS with React Native

Tags: rest, react-native, axios, background-process

I have a react native app making HTTP calls using Axios.

On one of the screen, a call is sent to the API. If I put the app in background before the call finishes, I have this kind of error in the `error.request` [block](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors).

```
{
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
    },
    "baseURL": "https://api.company.com",
    "method": "get",
    "params": {},
    "url": "https://api.company.com/pages/1"
  },
  "request": {
    "UNSENT": 0,
    "OPENED": 1,
    "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
    "LOADING": 3,
    "DONE": 4,
    "readyState": 4,
    "status": 0,
    "timeout": 0,
    "withCredentials": true,
    "upload": {},
    "_aborted": false,
    "_hasError": true,
    "_method": "GET",
    "_response": "Lost connection to background transfer service",
    "_url": "https://api.company.com/pages/1",
    "_timedOut": false,
    "_trackingName": "unknown",
    "_incrementalEvents": false,
    "_requestId": null,
    "_headers": {},
    "_responseType": "",
    "_sent": true,
    "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {},
    "_subscriptions": []
  }
}
```

How can I avoid the `Lost connection to background transfer service` error ? I experimented the "background" task plugins but they don't fit our needs since it is only a regular API call, not a long running task.

Comment: I am facing same problem Any updates on this ? @c4K

Comment: I had to run the code in a background thread on iOS via a NativeModule

Comment: @c4k can you please guide me about which native module you used, I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It was a home made one at work. I'm unfortunately not allowed to share it ;)